# Reverse keyboard TAB (Shift+Tab) in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

i am new to `protractor javascript` and i have a scenario for reverse `TAB (Shift+Tab)`. can anyone please advise.

Comment: this question needs a lot more detail.

Comment: var search = element(by.name('q'));
    search.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);  // this is for forward tab , i want to know how can i do reverse tab

Comment: @peter - if you add some more information in your question, then it will be easy to answer. Also this question and answer will become useful for others in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SHIFT`+`TAB` can be done via [`chord()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.Key.chord):

```
search.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.SHIFT, protractor.Key.TAB));
```

Comment: Hi Alec, i have similar question to the above, how can i input number keys in protractor.